# $(0,2)$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space. Then what will be that one point which will make $(0,2)$ a compact Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

If $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff , there exists a compact Hausdorff space $Y$ such that $Y-X$ consists of a single point. This theorem is taken from Mukresh. But I have a doubt.

$(0,2)$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space. Then what will be that one point which will make $(0,2)$ a compact Haudorff space?

Comment: Identify the endpoints, and you get a circle.

Comment: so we can not get a compact space in $R$?@user296602

Comment: @cmi Yes, there is no one point in $\mathbb{R}$ that can be adjoined to $(0, 2)$ so that the subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ becomes compact.

Comment: It's homeomorphic to $\{(\cos(\pi x),\sin(\pi x))\,|\,x\in(0,2)\}$.

Comment: Similarly adding that one point to the open disk $D=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2<1\}$ turns it into a sphere. Think of the new point as the North pole and the rest of the disk wrapped around it so that the closer to the periimeter the point on the disk is, the closer to the North pole it will go.

Comment: If $W$ is a connected subspace of $\Bbb R$ with compact closure,  such that $W\setminus \{q\}$ is disconnected for every $q\in W,$ then $W$ is a non-empty bounded open interval.....  From this we can show that if $(0,2)$ is a subspace of a compact Hausdorff space $V,$ and  if $g :V\to g(V)\subset \Bbb R$ is a homeomorphism, then $Cl_V(X) \setminus X=g^{-1}\{\inf g(X),\sup g(X)\}$ is a set with exactly $2$ members. So $V$ cannot be a $1$-point compactification of $X.$

Comment: But the theorem in Mukresh is saying there will be  a compact Hausdorff $Y$ which contains $X$ provided $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff. But here you are  saying $Y$ = the unit circle. How $(0,2)$ will be contained in unit circle?@JohnWaylandBales

Answer (score 0):

Let $T_X$ be a locally compact, non-compact  Hausdorff topology on $X.$ Let $p$ be some (any) point not in $X$ and let  $Y=\{p\}\cup X.$ Let $C$ be the set of all compact subsets of $X,$ with respect to the topology $T_X.$  Define a topology on $Y$ as $T_Y=T_X\cup \{Y\setminus c:C\in C\}.$

It is straightforward to show that $T_Y$ is a compact Hausdorff topology on $Y,$ and that the topology on $X,$ as a subspace of $Y,$ is $T_X.$ (And also that $X$  is dense in $Y$ and open in $Y.$)

It may be convenient to take a space $(X', T_{X'})$  that is homeomorphic to $(X,T_X),$  where $(X', T_{X'})$  is a dense open subspace of  a compact Hausdorff space $(Y', T_{Y'}),$ such that $Y'\setminus X'$ contains a single point $p$.

For example  with $X=(0,2),$ the function  $f(x)=e^{\pi i (x-1)}$  maps $X$ homeomorpically to $X'=Y'\setminus \{-1\},$ where $ Y'= \{z\in \Bbb C:|z|=1\}.... $

....  so let $p=-1$  and let $Y=X\cup \{-1\}.$ And extend the function $f:X\to X'$ to $f:Y\to Y'$ by letting $f(p)=p.$

Now let $U\subset Y$ be open in $Y$ iff $\{f(u):u\in U\}$ is open in $Y'.$

As to what this topology on $Y=(0,2)\cup \{-1\}$ "looks like":  If $U \subset Y$ then $U$ is open in $Y$ iff

(i). $U\cap (0,2)$ is open in $X=(0,2),$ and

(ii). if $(-1)\in U$ then $U\supset (0,r_0)$ and $U\supset (r_2,2)$ for some $r_0,r_2\in (0,2).$

Comment: I just started to read the concept of local compactness from Mukresh. Now I do not think I am eligible to understand your answer. But I will try to understand in 2 days as soon as I will be done with this chapter.@Daniel Wainfleet

Comment: Different authors  have different definitions for locally compact, although the ones I've seen are equivalent for Hausdorff spaces.